# SSMS Linked Server Connection to Azure Database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I know, I know... not a new question.  But maybe someone will say something differently this time such that the fix presents itself?

I can successfully connect to my Azure database as a connection in SSMS.  However, setting it up as a linked server is failing.  I'm setting it up as:

- Other data source
- provider:  Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
- Data source:  [myazureinstancename].database.windows.net
- Catalog:  [myazuredbname]

Then I'm choosing connections will be made using this security context and providing a valid login and password.

Port 1433 is open.

Named Pipes is disabled.

TCP/IP is enabled.

And yet I get the dreaded... "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]"

From what I understand that error 53 speaks of a connection error.  Should I be able to ping "[myazureinstancename].database.windows.net"?  I cannot.

Sorry again for asking, but any assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, Happy Holidays to all!  Secondly, more details (but sadly no progress).

• I can successfully connect to my Azure database in SSMS and successfully query it directly
• I can successfully create a Linked Server to my Azure database
• I can successfully manually run an SSIS package “immediately” against my Azure database

• I cannot “browse” to that Linked Server in SSMS
• I cannot execute a query against that Linked Server
• I cannot execute a saved SSIS package (the same package that runs successfully “immediately”) that runs against my Azure database as an SSMS job

Comment: Lots of hours in this one... tried lots of things.  I expect the fix will be something smallish, but it's certainly being elusive at the moment.

Needless to say, all I want for Christmas is to get this resolved...

Thanks for any assistance you may be able to provide!

Comment: 5 years later, has anyone found an answer to this question, is a Linked Server do-able if the DB is on Azure SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

I think its an IP-Address issue. For this you must add your IP-Address to your Azure SQL-DB Firewall settings as follows:[image]

If the problem still persists, then refer this bellow link:

[Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f398623b-d32b-4bf9-b2a6-4cce10ecd7d3/named-pipes-provider-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-53?forum=sqldataaccess)

[SQL SERVER – FIX : ERROR : (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server)](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Sadly it's not that as I've allowed my IP as a firewall rule, as evidenced by the fact that I can successfully connect to my Azure database as a connection in SSMS - it's just connecting to it as a Linked Server that's failing.  So frustrating...